# Why can't I run optimized code on Google Firebase Hosting?

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-hosting

I have an Angular 8 app and a Firebase Hosting Spark Plan.

I have one website working. But a second site I am trying to deploy only works if I use

`$ ng build --prod --optimization=false`

instead of preferred

`$ ng build --prod --aot`

When I use firebase hosting, either locally via **firebase serve** or deployed to server the page doesn't load and I get an obscure error in console. If I use --debug flag with **firebase serve** I get: 
`ERROR Error: "Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: OC(...).firestore is not a function`

This doesn't happen with ng serve

Any clue why I can't run optimized code?
Any suggestions for debugging this?

Comment: Please define "can't run". Errors?

Comment: Yes. I get an error that is not very helpful: ERROR Error: "[object Object]"

Comment: Where do you get the error? compile time or at run time? You need to please update your question to show the code around that error so we can help you.

Comment: I get an error when I run `firebase serve` after building --prod. If I do not use --prod I wont get an error. Also, if I use the --debug flag with serve I get: ERROR Error: "Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: OC(...).firestore is not a function... I don't have any trouble building --prod --aot then using ng serve. Only when using firebase hosting.